# sort an array of objects based on previous and next id

Tags: javascript, sorting, ecmascript-6, linked-list

I have an array of task objects containing previous and next task ids. I need to display an array of tasks which are sorted based on previous and next task ids. For example:

My input task array is

```
 [
    {
    "taskId": "101",
    "previousTaskId":"0",
    "nextTaskId":"102"
    },

    {
    "taskId": "103",
    "previousTaskId":"102",
    "nextTaskId":"0"
    },

    {
    "taskId": "102",
    "previousTaskId":"101",
    "nextTaskId":"103"
    }
]
```

My output task array is:

```
[
    {
    "taskId": "101",
    "previousTaskId":"0",
    "nextTaskId":"102"
    },

    {
    "taskId": "102",
    "previousTaskId":"101",
    "nextTaskId":"103"
    },

    {
    "taskId": "103",
    "previousTaskId":"102",
    "nextTaskId":"0"
    }
]
```

Is there any way to implement it using es6 methods? I am trying to use reduce and map functionality

```
const sortedTasks = tasks.reduce((acc, task) => {
    let {taskId, previousTaskId, nextTaskId} = task;
    return {...acc, task.map(function(item){
        if(item.previousTaskId === 0) //first position
            //how to compare with another taskId and assign it to acc ?

         })
    };
}, {});
```

Comment: what baout zero as id? do you have always zero at start and end?

Comment: Why don't you use built in sort function?

Comment: The input array is coming from an ajax call and yes the first object.previousTaskId is always 0 and endObject.nextTaskId is 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build a reference from each predecessor to the node and build the result from zero.

```js
function sort(array) {
    const
        temp = data.reduce((t, o) => {
            t[o.previousTaskId] = o;
            return t;
        }, {}),
        result = [];
    
    let p = '0';
    while (temp[p]) {
        result.push(temp[p]);
        p = temp[p]?.taskId;
    }
    return result;
}

const
    data = [{ taskId: "101", previousTaskId: "0", nextTaskId: "102" }, { taskId: "103", previousTaskId: "102", nextTaskId: "0" }, { taskId: "102", previousTaskId: "101", nextTaskId: "103" }];

console.log(sort(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . Just to understand the code, I usually use ternary operator with ? followed by :  I am slightly confused, What does this line mean p = temp[p]?.taskId;

Comment: it is the [optional chaining operator `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Comment: I see. If a reference is null or undefined, the expression short-circuits with a return value of undefined, instead of causing an error.  Thanks